# Question about rest api, How to correctly send a post request

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-core

for example, spring boot has annotations for certain methods (post, get, request body, etc..)

What attributes should be supplied for the arguments in the method, for example:

```
    [HttpPost]
  public async Task<List<ShowModelAttributes>> showModels(#here string str, #and here 
                                             string token)
    {
         return await serviceFromGetStatus.sendRestArrayOrderId(str, token);
    }
```

that is, when there is more than one argument.

also please, is there any detailed documentation on these attributes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/14722448 This is a pretty in depth guide I'd defiantly check it out

Comment: @Skyhighjinks I have the logic in the service. I need to register attributes in the controller, but I don't know which ones to use

Comment: @IanKemp No. I need information about [HttpPost],   HttpGet], [PostBody] and etc..

Comment: You don't need arguments... just bind the model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @pcalkins Yes,still would have shown what to put on my example for arguments, there would be no price. Thank you! )